# Open specific URL on successful login to noVNC

Tags: rdp, vnc, vnc-server, websockify, novnc

I have setup vnc server and access it using [noVnc](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC), works really good.

On every successful login I want to do the following:

1. Open up google-chrome - This can be done by adding chrome to startup applications.
2. Open a different URL everytime, so this has to be passed from my browser during login. On every login open up it up on chrome.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about VNC but you should be able to configure a script to run at startup if you can configure a program to run, say a `.bat` or `.sh` file.

Within this file you have a few ways of launching Chrome with a specific URL:

**1. Shortcut files, and choosing one randomly.**

You could have many in a folder, and your startup script chooses one at random.

```
╔══════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║ Protocol ║ Target         ║ Result                          ║
╠══════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║ HTTP     ║ www.google.com ║ googlechrome://www.google.com/  ║
║ HTTPS    ║ www.google.com ║ googlechromes://www.google.com/ ║
╚══════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

**2. Launching Chrome directly with a random URL.**

Make a script to pass the following, you can specify incognito by using the `-incognito` flag.

```
chrome.exe https://google.com
```